# Disabling a button based until data is received from the api response in react

Tags: reactjs

I prepared a demo based on a project that I'm working.
[Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts99km?file=src/App.js)

I have a state variable in `NewExportRequestStore` as `isCalculationLoadHw`. `isCalculationLoadHw` is set to true before an api call and false after receiving the response from the api in both the methods in the `NewExportRequestStore`. But here I simulated it as `setimeout`.

```
import {useState} from "react";
interface INewExportRequestState
{
   state:{
        isCalculationLoadHw:boolean;            
   }
}

interface INewExportRequestStoreActions
{
   actions:{
        getCalDraftHW():void;
        getCalDraftSW():void;
   }
}


const useNewExportRequestStore = ():INewExportRequestStoreActions & 
  INewExportRequestState => {

const[isCalculationLoaddHw,setCalculationLoadHw] = useState(false);

const getCalDraftHW =():void=>{
    setCalculationLoadHw(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
        setCalculationLoadHw(false);
    }, 3000);

}

const getCalDraftSW =():void =>{
    setCalculationLoadHw(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
        setCalculationLoadHw(false);
    }, 3000);
}

return {
    state:{            
        isCalculationLoadHw
    },
    actions:{
        getCalDraftHW,
        getCalDraftSW
    }
}
}

export default useNewExportRequestStore;
```

The buttons in `NewCalculation`, `NewSwCalculation` get disabled as per the change in the state but the button in the child component `NewChildSwCalculation` doesn't get disabled based on the state variable.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import useNewExportRequestStore from './Contract/NewExportRequestStore';

const NewCalculation =() =>{
const {state,actions} = useNewExportRequestStore();
useEffect(()=>{
    actions.getCalDraftHW();
},[]);

return (
    <div>
        Hello from New Calculation.
        <button disabled={state.isCalculationLoadHw?true:false}>Calculate</button>
    </div>

);
}

export default NewCalculation;
```

NewSwCalculation.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import useNewExportRequestStore from "./Contract/NewExportRequestStore";
import NewChildSwCalculation from "./NewChildSwCalculation";

const SwCalculation = () =>{
const {state,actions} = useNewExportRequestStore();
useEffect(()=>{ actions.getCalDraftSW(); },[]);

return (
    <div>
        Hello from Software Calculation
        <button disabled={state.isCalculationLoadHw}>Export</button>
        <NewChildSwCalculation/>
    </div>
);
}

export default SwCalculation;
```

NewChildSwCalculation.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import useNewExportRequestStore from "./Contract/NewExportRequestStore";

const NewChildSwCalculation =() =>{
const {state,actions} = useNewExportRequestStore();
return(
        <div>
             Hello from the Child Sw Calculation
             <button disabled={state.isCalculationLoadHw}>
             Export Child Sw
             </button>
         </div>
        );
 }

export default NewChildSwCalculation;
```

I'm unsure how to disable the button in the child component based on the `isCalculationLoadHw`

Comment: Everytime you use `useNewExportRequestStore()` hook, you basically define new state variables for each component this hook uses. Lift the state up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I tried lifting the state into the App.js in the example at [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts99km?file=src/NewSwCalculation.tsx](Stack Blitz) but I get error ```Create is not a function ```